# Is it possible to add/inject an instance of a Widget into many panels?

Tags: gwt

I've tried doing this but only one panel gets the Widget shown. What is the approach to add an instance of a Widget into many panels? Or is it even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by inject, you mean use some DI tool (like Guice), then yes, you can inject the instance into many other instances as a singleton (just like any other singleton).

However, a given Widget can only be rendered in one place at a time. Elements can be cloned, but there is no general method of copying a widget to draw it in more than one place, mostly due to all of the event handlers that have to be added again.

Answer (score 0):

How would then this method work?

```
Widget getParent()
    Gets this widget's parent panel.
```

So you have to create multiple instances. Btw what's your use case?

Comment: I'm injecting a widget in many "Views" (as in MVC); Which based class is a Composite.

Comment: Not actually, I was passing the same instance, I guess I may need to do some cloning.